# Avoid an 'ls' style listing on actvation virtualenv/wrapper

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I've just installed, and when I activate a `virtualenv`, I get a listing of files and directories in the `.virtualenvs` directory. My `zsh` does a directory listing on entering a directory, but I'd like to be able to skip this.

This is only the second time I've installed `virtualenvwrapper`, and I'm not sure why it's an issue now.

A quick hacky solution for me is to change my `cd` function to skip listing:

```bash
cd(){
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    case "$1" in
        "$HOME/.virtualenvs")
            :
        ;;
        *)
            builtin cd "$@"&&ls -lah --color=auto
        ;;
    esac
else
    builtin cd ~&&ls -lah --color=auto
fi
}
```

If there is a solution in `virtualenvwrapper` itself, that seems preferable then having to check on every `cd`, but this works for now.

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution to this problem? Thank you for providing the solution that you did, as it looks like it will solve my problem, just eyeballing it.

Comment: Also, where did you place this? I assume in the .zshrc file, but does it need to be above any other important commands?

Comment: I was just thinking about posting a bounty on this, as it's a legitimate concern of mine, don't think I can find any other question covering it, and been awhile as well.

Comment: This just goes in the .zshrc, or whereever you load your zsh functions. I haven't found another solution, yet, and this has been effective enough.